# Unity. Switching to an object after creation

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm using a 2D `Deck` object as a deck for a card game, which when called on `OnMouseDown()` will spawn another `Card` object on top of it. How, after clicking on `Deck`, can you instantly switch to `Card`, so that, for example, the `OnMouseDrag()` method starts to be called on it, without releasing the mouse button?

I tried to call `OnMouseDrag()` on `Card` directly from `OnMouseDown()` on `Deck`, but it didn't work.

Comment: did you read the unity documentation on draganddrop? and doing it by code?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about OnMouseDrag() but you could simply set the location of the card to the x,y location of your mouse if and only if the card was clicked & mouse 1 is being held down.